# Turn off monitor backlight (DPMS) from a VC/VT (TTY) without Xorg/Wayland-DE

Tags: linux, console, monitors, backlight, dpms

How does one flip a monitor's backlight on/off from the normal Linux console (tty1)?

I'm looking for a way to do this without dependencies on Xorg or specific Wayland-Compositors.

Let's say, that I want to toggle the backlight of the monitor connected to `/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1`.

EDIT: Putting a specific monitor into standby mode from tty1 would suffice as an answer.

`vbetool` seems to work, but there doesn't seem to be a way that affects just one specific monitor instead of all of them.

`ddcutil setvcp D6 x05` let me turn off one of my monitors. Again, how does one select which one with these tools?

Comment: With some chance, this could be controlled by ACPI. Can you list something in the /sys/class/backlight directory ?

Comment: The ```/sys/class/backlight``` dir is empty.

Comment: Too bad ! OK then ! Ready for not recommended methods ? (Firing data directly to cards' registers ?) You can then try lspci to find where your graphic card is then use setpci -s to that location in order to force some value somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, monitor backlights can’t be toggled on or off without acting on the overall [DPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling) status (*i.e.* the monitor’s overall power status). However if your monitor is controllable through [DDC/CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel#DDC/CI), you can use that to set the DPMS status and brightness level. (You may need to enable DDC/CI in your monitor’s settings.)

The first thing to try, before DDC/CI, is `setterm`; this allows the kernel’s own VT blanking to be configured (this will trigger DPMS):

- To change modes immediately,

  ```
  sudo setterm --powersave <mode>
  ```

  where `<mode>` can be `on`, `powerdown`, `off` (and a couple of other values which aren’t as useful).
- To change the blanking delay,

  ```
  sudo setterm --blank=<n>
  ```

  where `<n>` is the delay in minutes (0 to disable, maximum 60).
- To change the powerdown delay,

  ```
  sudo setterm --powerdown=<n>
  ```

  with the same values as `--blank`.

A number of tools provide DDC/CI access from the Linux console. For example, using [`ddccontrol`](https://github.com/ddccontrol/ddccontrol):

- Install the `i2c-dev` module if necessary:

  ```
  sudo modprobe i2c-dev
  ```
- Probe your devices:

  ```
  sudo ddccontrol -p
  ```

  This will list devices it finds, and the available controls. Look for `/dev/i2c-…` results, and the controls for “Power control” and “Brightness and Contrast”.
- Change your power settings (using the control address and values listed above); to force your monitor to standby:

  ```
  sudo ddccontrol -r 0xd6 -w 4 dev:/dev/i2c-9
  ```

  (these values are appropriate for the monitor I’m using; they might not be for yours, and the device will in all likelihood be different).

Many of the controls available through your monitor’s buttons or on-screen menus should also be available through DDC/CI. In particular, you should be able to adjust brightness and contrast, change input sources (if your monitor has multiple inputs), adjust colours…

If you want to control your monitor’s brightness using `/sys/class/backlight`, check out [the `ddcci-driver-linux` module](https://gitlab.com/ddcci-driver-linux/ddcci-driver-linux) (available as `ddcci-dkms` in Debian and derivatives).

Comment: Both the setterm and ddccontrol methods don't work for me :(

According to ddcontrol, one of my monitors (dev:/dev/i2c-5) has the same 'Power control' values as yours (name=DPMS Control, address=0xd6 ... id=standby - name=Standby, value=4), but when I try to put it into standby nothing happens.

Comment: You might need to enable DDC/CI in your monitor’s settings, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: I activated DDC/CI in the OSD, but it still does not work. (Btw, none of my monitors is supported by ddccontrol (it says so in the probe output) - forgot to mention that.). (DPMS works fine, when my window manager (sway) does it, btw.)

Comment: The `ddccontrol` database is very incomplete, my monitors aren’t in it either. I would have thought `setterm` would work though, given that DPMS works from Sway :-/